# How to hide a tabbar at the app startup?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, tabbar

So, I want my app starts with a UIViewController(without seeing a tabbar), and then enter a UITableView with navigationbar and tabbar.  the problem is that the Tabbar is visible at the app starts up, anyone can help on this will be very appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should either send -presentModalViewController:animated: to your main UIViewController with the tab bar controller as an argument or just do this:

```
[myWindow addSubview: myTabBarController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your app a navigation based application (rather than a tab bar based one) then add a tab bar on the UITableView.

There is help for adding the UITabBar [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html)

I do it like this : in this case drawing a table view and map view (From the Locati application)

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];          // creates your tab bar so you can add everything else to it

searchTableViewController = [[SearchTableViewController alloc] init];               // creates your table view - this should be a UIViewController with a table view in it, or UITableViewController
UINavigationController *searchTableNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchTableViewController] autorelease];
[searchTableViewController release];                                                              // creates your table view's navigation controller, then adds the view controller you made. Note I then let go of the view controller as the navigation controller now holds onto it 

searchMapViewController = [[SearchMapViewController alloc] init];   
UINavigationController *mapTableNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchMapViewController] autorelease];
[searchMapViewController release];                                                    // does exactly the same as the first round, but for your second tab at the bottom of the bar.

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchTableNavController, mapTableNavController,  nil]; //add both of your navigation controllers to the tab bar. You can put as many controllers on as you like
```

I found this pattern a long time ago. Sorry that I can't point at the original.
YOu then need to add the tabbarcontoller to the relevant view ([...view addSubView:tabBarController];) possibly setting frame first.

Comment: yes my app is a navigation based application, the mainwindow calls UITableView with a tabbar and navigation bar, I think that's why the tabbar is shown at the startup view(it's a UIViewController). it will be appreciated if you could post some sample code..

Comment: my app is a TabBar based app, is this the problem to load an UIView which without tabbar controller visible??

Comment: yes. Make a view based app. Add the tab bar to the screens that you want a tab bar on.